# Calling the list created using getlist on the form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In my Django project, I save the data in a field that I have made multiple selections to the database using the getlist function and the POST method. Then I pull this data from the database and print it on an html form, but I cannot access the list data properly unless I split it here.

views.py

```
def record_form(request): 
    if request.method == "POST" and 'registrationSave' in request.POST:
        records = Records()
        

        records.medications = request.POST.getlist('medications')
        records.scale_used = request.POST.getlist('scale_used')
        
        records.save()
        return redirect('/index/tables')
```

```
def editRecords(request,id):
    edit_records = Records.objects.get(id=id)
    if edit_records.medications is not None:
        edit_records.medications = edit_records.medications.split(",")
    if edit_records.scale_used is not None:
        edit_records.scale_used = edit_records.scale_used.split(",")
    institutionName = Institution.objects.all()
    medicationName = MedicationName.objects.all()
    return render(request,"update_record.html",{"Records": edit_records,  
"institutionName":institutionName,"medicationName":medicationName})
```

`update.html`

```
 <div class="col-4">
                                                {% for medication in Records.medications%}
                                                <div class="mb-3 col">
                                                    <label for="">İlaç Adı:</label>
                                                    <select class="form-select" name="medications" id="medications">
                                                        <option {% if medication == '{{medicationName.medicationName}}' %} selected  {%endif%}>{{medication}}</option>        
                                                        {% if medicationName%}
                                                            <p>{{medicationName}}</p>
                                                            {% for medicationName in medicationName %}
                                                                <option value="{{medicationName.medicationName}}">{{medicationName.medicationName}}</option>
                                                            {%endfor%}
                                                        {%endif%}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                {%endfor%}
                                            </div>
```

I'm sharing my code pieces above with you, and I'm leaving the screenshot of the update.html page below. How can I follow a method to avoid [ ] and ' ' signs?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0qud.png)

Thank you in advance for your help